# Need design advice for exclusive access to private class state

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a simple system I'm working on that involves serializing user objects. I have a series of specialized template classes that act on each type to be read/write differently:

```
template<class T>
class ItemSerializer;

template<>
class ItemSerializer<int>
{
public:
    static void store( int const& obj )
    {
    }

    static void fetch( int& obj )
    {
    }
};

template<>
class ItemSerializer<NoteNumberArray>
{
public:
    static void store( NoteNumberArray const& obj )
    {
       // NoteNumberArray::_blocks is used here.
    }

    static void fetch( NoteNumberArray& obj )
    {
       // NoteNumberArray::_blocks is used here.
    }
};
```

Depending on the type, it may or may not have state with it, which is necessary for the serializer class to which it is assigned. In this example, I have serializers for 2 types: `int` and `NoteNumberArray`. The store/fetch functions do not need any additional state for `int` types, the read/write implementation is very simple.

However, for `NoteNumberArray`, state is necessary so I create my own class instead of using core types or STL types. This state is used by the implementation of `ItemSerializer` *only*, for optimization purposes. This private state would be used to optimize the speed and efficiency of the read/write methods. Since the serializer classes are not stateful, I put this state in the user object instead.

I could probably make `ItemSerializer` a friend of `NoteNumberArray`, but this would cause a circular dependency and gives `ItemSerializer` access to more of `NoteNumberArray` than might be necessary.

What is a good design for such a system? Just looking for some tips to help me get started. Here is some other relevant snippets for this example:

```
class Block
{
};

class NoteNumberArray
{
public:
    // Public interface, none of which will use _blocks. Only ItemSerializer uses _blocks.

private:
    std::vector<int> _array; // This should not be used directly by anyone, including ItemSerializer.
    std::vector<Block> _blocks; // This is the private state only used by ItemSerializer
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the circular dependency problem, there is no dependency issue making `ItemSerializer<NoteNumberArray>` a friend of `NoteNumberArray`.

I do see the access issue if you don't want `ItemSerializer<NoteNumberArray>` to be able to see other private parts of `NoteNumberArray`.

One possibility is to wrap `_blocks` into another class `NoteNumberArraySerializerHelper`, which has `ItemSerializer<NoteNumberArray>` as a friend and all methods (including constructors and other things that would normally be written for you by the compiler) private. Then you'd have to give public accessor/mutator methods for `_blocks` to `NoteNumberArray` but nobody except `ItemSerializer<NoteNumberArray>` could use those methods to do anything.

Comment: There WILL be a circular dependency. `NoteNumberArray` needs the definition of `ItemSerializer` for the `friend class` statement. Also, `ItemSerializer::store()` will need the implementation of `NoteNumberArray` to use it, access its members, etc.

Comment: No, `NoteNumberArray` only needs your forward declaration of `template<class T> class ItemSerializer;` for the friend declaration `friend class ItemSerializer<NoteNumberArray>;` to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If `_blocks` is only used by `ItemSerializer` just make it a member of the `ItemSerializer` specialization instead. Without understanding the whole purpose, I can't see the advantage of storing such a thing in the `NoteNumberArray` directly.

As a side note, by avoiding leading `_` on your identifiers you can easily avoid accidentally using reserved names (such as `_` followed by capital or leading `_` in the global namespace).